# Get request using Jquery from another domain not working?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am creating a web application which hosted on a domain example.com, I would like to download a binary file of 1 MB to check the download speed, its working fine if binary file hosted on same domain.

But when I tried with another domain, it stops working. I tried the crossdomain property but noting happens.

My code is below:

```
    jQuery143.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example2.com/myfile.bin?id=xxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'application/octet-stream',
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

When I replaced "example2.com" with "example.com", its working fine. So please let me know how can I resolved this issue.

I put the crossdomain.xml on example2.com, so request status is OK.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 1):

you can try sending datatype as "jsonp" for cross domain request and you can check this link for help [Cross domain Get with Jquery](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) and also this link helps you to get started [remote JsonP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

from [Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is not allowing to make a cross domain call. JSONP seems to be only option if you are calling from browser.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: same issue with jsonp,  but it allowed json content type, I have to download binaly file,

Comment: You need to wrap the content of the file inside a Javascript method. name the method should be same as callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the 'crossDomain' parameter to true for cross domain request.
Please check this one http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/